# How to prove that the following trace is a circle

Tags: circles

$$\Gamma = { B\over e^{j\theta} -A}$$

Both $A$ and $B$ are complex numbers.

The tedious way of course is to expand $A$, $B$ and $e^{j\theta}$, formulate the function into the form of $\Gamma = x + jy$, then prove $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$.

But I wonder whether there's a more clever way...

High school was such a long time ago and I find myself unable to come up with clever tricks any more...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$z = e^{j\theta}$ for real $\theta$ traces out the unit circle.  A linear fractional transformation such as $z \to B/(z - A)$ takes circles (and straight lines) to circles (or straight lines).  If $A$ is on the unit circle the image is a straight line; if not, it is a circle.

EDIT: For convenience we may assume  $B = 1$  (since scalings and rotations take circles to circles).  Suppose $|A| \ne 1$. Let $p = \dfrac{\overline{A}}{1-|A|^2}$.  Then 
$$ \frac{1}{e^{j\theta} - A} - p =  \frac{1-\overline{A} e^{j\theta}}{(e^{j\theta}-A)(1-|A|^2)}$$
But 
$$\left|1 - \overline{A} e^{j\theta}\right| = \left|e^{j\theta} (e^{-j\theta} - \overline{A})\right| = \left|e^{j\theta}-A\right|$$
so $$\left| \frac{1}{e^{j\theta} - A} - p \right| = \frac{1}{|1-|A|^2|}$$
is constant.  Thus $\dfrac{1}{e^{j\theta}-A}$ describes a circle with centre $p$ and radius $1/{|1 - |A|^2|}$.

I'll leave the case $|A|=1$ to you.

Comment: Thanks Dr. Israel. It's all clear now.